# Clean networktraffic or cache on homepage

Tags: angularjs, html, video

Excuse me for my bad title but I couldn't describe my error in a better way.
On our website we are using a HTML5 video tag with a mp4 video and a webm video. The size of these videos is 1MB each.

We are working with angularJs.

Now the real question:
When I check the network traffic on a website with a video background like airbnb I see that everytime I click on the 'Home' icon the network traffic is cleared and everything is loaded again.

In our website, when we click on the home icon (it's just a simple anchor tag with a href attribute) the network traffic isn't cleared at all. In fact the new requests are added to the existing ones. This will cause the problem that once Chrome says 10MB transferred, the whole website is stuck...

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The home icon is just a 'button' or some other attribute on the web page - what it does will depend on how the web page is coded.

It sounds like on your app the home button is simply changing what is displayed to the user without reloading the whole web page, which is a typical behaviour on a single page app built with a framework like Angular.

On the other sites you are comparing too it sounds like the home button is set up to trigger a web page reload, i.e. a full new HTTP request to the server. Most of the browser development consoles will reset the information they have captured in he console and network tabs etc.

Note that this clearing of data is just a debugging view - for network traffic in particular, once it has happened to can't be made 'unhappen', if this makes sense. All that is occurring here is that the record of the network traffic in the development tool view is being cleaned up - this is usually done to make it easier to see the communication associated with a new page request.